# How to make this product pipeline figure?

Tags: charts, timeline

[image]

Is there a way to make such a figure?

I tried gantt charts, but those aren't what I wanted.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

%
% This is a direct copy of the codes in section 2.9 of the package
% documentation (See page 45) https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf 
% except the color setting


\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}
\definecolor{groupblue}{RGB}{51,102,254}
\definecolor{linkred}{RGB}{165,0,33} 

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
    y unit title=0.4cm,
    y unit chart=0.5cm,
    vgrid,
    time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,
    compress calendar,
    title/.append style={draw=none, fill=barblue},
    title label font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},
    title label node/.append style={below=-1.6ex},
    title left shift=.05,
    title right shift=-.05,
    title height=1,
    bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=groupblue},
    bar height=.6,
    bar label font=\normalsize\color{black!50},
    group right shift=0,
    group top shift=.6,
    group height=.3,
    group peaks height=.2,
    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=green}
   ]{2019-09}{2020-12}
   \gantttitlecalendar{year}\\
   \ganttbar[
    progress=100,
    bar progress label font=\small\color{barblue},
    bar progress label node/.append style={right=4pt},
    bar label font=\normalsize\color{barblue},
    name=pp
   ]{}{2019-09}{2019-12} \\
\ganttset{progress label text={}, link/.style={black, -to}}
\ganttgroup{Virus}{2020-01}{2020-12} \\
\ganttbar[progress=4, name=T1A]{}{2020-01}{2020-06} \\

\ganttgroup{Objective 2}{2020-01}{2020-12} \\
\ganttbar[progress=15, name=T2A]{}{2020-01}{2020-09} \\

\ganttgroup{Objective 3}{2020-05}{2020-08} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=0]{}{2020-05}{2020-08}
  \ganttset{link/.style={green}}
  \ganttlink[link mid=.4]{pp}{T1A}
  \ganttlink[link mid=.159]{pp}{T2A}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! It is straightforward to produce this with a `matrix of nodes` of Ti*k*Z. However, if you expect others to punch in the texts from the screen shot, you may get disappointed.

Comment: I was looking for an abstract representation with the right number of columns and a general idea how to make the progress bars.

Comment: None of this is a problem. Ti*k*Z has shapes for those called `signal` (with rounded corners). The problem is that there is literally nothing in your post to build on except for a screen shot.

Comment: Question edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a matrix. Everything is straightforward except for filling in the the texts. I wish this was not necessary, then there would be much more time for explanations.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.symbols,fit,calc}
\definecolor{mgreen}{RGB}{120,172,76}
\definecolor{mblue}{RGB}{81,123,189}
\definecolor{myellow}{RGB}{237,201,69}
\definecolor{mred}{RGB}{189,80,52}  
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newbox\eqnodebox
\tikzset{equal size/.style={execute at begin
    node={\setbox\eqnodebox=\hbox\bgroup},
    execute at end node={\egroup\eqmakebox[#1][\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/equal size align}]{\copy\eqnodebox}}},
    equal size/.default=A,equal size align/.initial=l,
    equal column/.style={column #1/.style={nodes={equal size=A#1}}},
    msig/.style={signal,signal to=east,signal
    from=nowhere,double=black,draw=white,rounded corners=1.5pt,
    minimum height=1.2em,inner xsep=-1pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
    %h/.style={minimum height={2pt+#1*1em-#1*1pt}}
    ]
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,
   equal column/.list={1,...,7},
%   fixed size/.list={4,5,6},
   nodes={minimum height=2.2em,anchor=west},
   column sep=1pt,row sep=1pt,
   row 1/.style={nodes={fill=gray!60!black,text=white,node font=\small,
   minimum height=3em}},
   row 2/.style={nodes={fill=mgreen!60}},
   row 3/.style={nodes={fill=mgreen!20}},
   row 4/.style={nodes={fill=mgreen!50}},
   row 5/.style={nodes={fill=myellow!60,minimum height=2.8em}},
   row 6/.style={nodes={fill=mblue!60}},
   row 7/.style={nodes={fill=mblue!80}},
   row 8/.style={nodes={fill=mred!60,minimum height=3em}},
 ] (mat) {
 Description & Disease & Preclinical  & 
 \begin{tabular}{c} Phase\\ 1 \end{tabular} & 
 \begin{tabular}{c} Phase\\ 2 \end{tabular} & 
 \begin{tabular}{c} Phase\\ 3 \end{tabular} & 
  Marketed \\
 & AML & & & & &\\
 & MDS & & & & &\\
 & NSCL& & & & & \\
 & CLL& & & & & \\
 & NSCLC& & & & & \\
 & Nasopharyngel& & & & & \\
 & Solid tumors& & & & & \\
 };
\begin{scope}[pfit/.style n args={3}{fit={(mat-#1-1.north west)
(mat-#2-1.south east)},inner sep=0pt,
label={[anchor=west,node font=\small,align=left]west:{#3}}}]
 \node[pfit={2}{4}{Sappa\\ pft pft pft},
  fill=mgreen!90]{};
 \node[pfit={5}{5}{Sappa\\ pft pft pft},anchor=center,
  fill=myellow!90]{};
 \node[pfit={6}{7}{Sappa\\ pft pft pft},anchor=center,
  fill=mblue!90]{};
 \node[pfit={8}{8}{Sappa\\ pft pft pft},anchor=center,
  fill=mred!90]{};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[nodes=msig]
 \node[fit=(mat-2-3.west) (mat-2-6.center),fill=mgreen]{};
 \node[fit=(mat-3-3.west) (mat-3-5.east),fill=mgreen]{};
 \node[fit={(mat-4-3.west) ($(mat-4-5.west)!0.8!(mat-4-5.east)$)},fill=mgreen]{};
 \node[fit={(mat-5-3.west) ($(mat-5-5.west)!0.6!(mat-5-5.east)$)},fill=myellow]{};
 \node[fit={(mat-6-3.west) ($(mat-6-5.west)!0.7!(mat-6-5.east)$)},fill=mblue]{};
 \node[fit={(mat-7-3.west) ($(mat-7-5.west)!0.2!(mat-7-5.east)$)},fill=mblue]{};
 \node[fit={(mat-8-3.west) ($(mat-8-4.west)!0.6!(mat-8-4.east)$)},fill=red]{};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]